# How to remove the duplicated of selectors using SASS

Tags: sass

```
ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.default,
ol.default {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

ul.default {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ol.default {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

As you can see, code above has so many duplicated CSS selector how to remove these duplications using SCSS correctly?

Comment: You have no duplicated CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` and do like:

```
ul, ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  &.default {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  }
}

ul.default {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

ol.default {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```